# Android WebView Caching Issue

Tags: android, webview

I am working on an Android application where I am using webview to display GIF files downloaded from internet, it is a picture viewer do user can click next and previous to view the next and previous gif files, the issue I am facing is that when user clicks next, for one split second it displays the older html and then updates the webview, I have tried disabling the webview cache but it is of no use, relevant part of the code is.

```
String base = Common.CACHE_IMAGES_PATH.getPath();
String imagePath = "file://" + base + "/" + forImage;
String html = "<html style=\"height:100%\"><head><META HTTP-EQUIV=\"CACHE-CONTROL\" CONTENT=\"NO-CACHE\"><META HTTP-EQUIV=\"PRAGMA\" CONTENT=\"NO-CACHE\"> </head><body  style=\"padding:0x;margin:0px; background-color:#999;height:100%\"><img id=\""
                + System.currentTimeMillis()
                + "\" align=\"middle\"  style=\"width:100%;height:auto;\" src=\""
                + imagePath + "\"></body></html>";
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(Common.FULL_IMAGE_BASE_URL + forImage
                + "?fix=" + System.currentTimeMillis(), html, "text/html",
                "utf-8", Common.FULL_IMAGE_BASE_URL + forImage + "?fix="
                        + System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Here I am reading the image from sdcard and displaying it in webview, this code is executed everytime user click next or previous.